Dense subset of $C^{1}_{c}([0, T); V)$, where $V$ is a Hilbert Space and $0< T < \infty$.
I was trying to understand the definition of a weak solution of an evolution equation of first order. And I got confused with the following questions-
Question 1. Can we say $C^{1}_{c}([0, T)\times \Omega)$ is a dense subset of $C^{1}_{c}([0, T); H^{1}_{0}(\Omega))$?
Question 2. Can we say that $\{u(t)v \mid u\in C^{1}_{c}([0, T); \mathbb{R}),\, v\in V\}$ is a dense subset of $C^{1}_{c}([0, T); V)$, where $V$ is a Hilbert space?
All the above spaces are considered as a subset of $L^{2}(0, T; V)$ where the norm is $\|u\|^{2}_{L^{2}(0, T; V)} = \int_{0}^{T} \|u(t)\|^{2}_{V}\, dt$. For the first question, take $V = H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$.
However, to solve the questions, one could take the following norms-
$$\sup\limits_{[0, T)}\|u(t)\|_{V}, \qquad \text{or} \qquad \sup\limits_{[0, T)}\,\{\|u(t)\|_{V} + \|u'(t)\|_{V}\}.$$
I would appreciate it if someone could help me to solve the above questions.

What norm do you have in $C^1_c$?

@daw I edited the question. Please take a look at your convenience. Thank you.
